# Can I know the encoding for texts used in this website?

Tags: php, html, encoding

[The website](http://www.eenadu.net/)

I am trying to display the telugu font I got the font file what they have used in this website.
Now I need to encode the text in the same format as the above website.
I have tried with html code, html ascii code etc. but unable to find to coded type.
Can anyone please find and is there a way to convert my text to that format in PHP.

The format they have use in the website is `¯äÊÕ

```
      &AElig;N-F-A-X&frac34;-&ordf;&frac12;&Otilde;-&#339;&Euml;-&Ecirc;&cent;{&Ouml;

      &AElig;&macr;&Atilde;o

      &pound;&frac34;&Ccedil;&egrave;&Ccedil;&ecirc;&ordf;

      &brvbar;&sect;&#338;&Otilde;-{-&aring;X-&#353;&Ccedil;d&Acirc;&sup1;

      &laquo;*a&Ecirc; &sup2;&ntilde;N&Otilde;tC.

      &AElig;&cent;&Aring;&#338;&Acirc;&sup1;&times;

      &laquo;&aacute;&cent;&#376;&iquest;&Otilde; <br>

      &macr;&auml;&ordf;&frac12;&Otilde;&#8217;&Atilde; &laquo;*a

      &copy;&cent;&Iacute;&Atilde;&copy;&Otilde;

      &#402;&laquo;y-&#353;&Ccedil;-E&Acirc;&Euml; &#8226;&Ecirc;&cent;

      &#8226;&cent;&ecirc;&Acirc;-&#8222;&Atilde;&ordf;&frac12;&Otilde;.&nbsp;`
```

You can also see this by right clicking on the website and view source.

Comment: (lol, there's two conflicting content-type meta headers on that page.)

Comment: @Mat that's alright, there is no conflict. The HTTP header itself also defines an encoding, which takes precedence. It's yet another encoding, by the way.

Comment: @amp Just write your text with the UTF-8 encoding, that'll do. Oh, but is this your website? Could you do something about the hundreds of errors and dozens of warnings the W3 validator reports?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the encoding of the *font*. Eenadu is an 8-bit font, with proprietary allocation of characters. This means that a page using it will display properly only when that particular font is available in the user’s system and the browser uses it. [This problem has existed for over ten years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165508), and nowadays they seem to use embedded (web) fonts, so the pages mostly seem to work (s-l-o-w-l-y). The approach has often been [protested against](http://fci.wikia.com/wiki/Eenadu).

If you wish to take that path, and not the standards-conforming way of using Unicode fonts, then I suggest that you ask for information on the encoding of the font from its distributor. Alternatively, you can reverse-engineer it by looking at character data containing all 8-bit bytes when the font is set to Eenadu.